# How much damage does the Fallen Champion from Genzaniku do?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Legendary Axe Genzaniku has an affix "Summon a Fallen Champion" but after some searching I haven't been able to determine his damage. I don't see any explanation on the [official blizzard page](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/genzaniku).

When I first equipped this item, I noticed that he "one-shotted" something that my character could not kill in one hit.

Is his damage fixed, tied to my damage stat as a percentage, or is he just a Fallen Champion tied to my (or my weapon's) clvl?

{edit} I no longer have this weapon, so it is not possible for me to test it myself currently.

Comment: +1 Great question.  I have a legendary that summons 5 skeletons to attack for me and the best way I've found out their damage is to just summon a few of them and test it out on enemies.  Maybe you can try that?  Once it summons, just stop attacking and watch the damage numbers.  In my case, each skeleton did a consistent ~150k dmg per attack in Torment 1 (level 70 - any act).

Comment: @Mkalafut I think it scales based on the character, the skeletons I have do 300k per hit.

Comment: I have a Legendary that summons "A herd of angry cattle" and am wondering what determines their damage as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a very interesting site that gives information about all of the summoned monsters/skeletons/cows:

> - The Fallen Champion lasts for 15 seconds or until killed and can be re-summoned immediately.
> - Deals around 100% weapon damage per swing.
> - Can rarely deal a power attack which deals 250% average weapon    damage.
> - As of Patch 2.0.4 (4-08-2014), the survivability of the Fallen    Champion was greatly increased.

[Source](http://www.diablohub.com/database/sorting/summon-monster/).

I'm unsure where they get their information from,but it seems pretty accurate.

Answer (score -1):

Every unique effect that deals damage is influenced primarily with your base damage in a way that the base dmg, crit chance, crit damage and attack speed bonuses attribute towards higher damage.

The base damage and exact mechanics of a fallen champion is unknown to me, but you can check for how much it hits as @Mkalafut said.

This champion has one "special" ability, that is, it can knockback enemies, just like the regular monster version can knock you back. Although that does not happen that often you can still use it as a slight crowd control and combine with Strongarm Bracers and its unique effect for bonus damage.